# Autosize of TextFrame for a specific table cell in PowerPoint presentation programmatically

Tags: c#, cell, autosize, powerpoint-2010

I got the next situation.
Got some variables:

```
        PowerPoint.Application objApp;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape oShape;
        PowerPoint.Presentations objPresSet;
        PowerPoint._Presentation objPres;
        PowerPoint.Slides objSlides;
        PowerPoint._Slide objSlide;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape oShape;
```

I'm creating a PowerPoint 2010 slide presentation:

```
        objApp = new PowerPoint.Application();
        objApp.Visible = MsoTriState.msoTrue;
        objPresSet = objApp.Presentations;
        objPres = objPresSet.Open(strTemplate, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoTrue);
        objSlides = objPres.Slides;
```

Here I'm creating a slide:

```
        objSlide = objSlides.Add(2, PowerPoint.PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutTitleOnly);
```

For the next step I add the table to slide:

```
        int rows = 4;
        int cells = 10;
        oShape = objSlide.Shapes.AddTable(rows, cells, 10, 10, 400, 450);
```

And I don't have any problems with text adding to a specific cell:

```
        oShape.Table.Cell(1, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Dummy Text";
```

But, the cell does not want to stretch.
I tried to modify `TextFrame` with `AutoSize` property:

```
        oShape.Table.Cell(1, 1).Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = MsoAutoSize.msoAutoSizeTextToFitShape;
```

And here I'm getting the "ArgumentException":

> The specified value is out of range.

Any thoughts why it's happening?
If no, are there another way to stretch table cell?

Comment: To change the size of a table cell, you change the size of the shape that it represents:   oShape.Table.Cell(1, 1).Shape.Width=xxx and so on

Comment: Hey Steve. I tried. NotImplementedException was unhandlend.

Comment: Sorry, my bad.  You can't change the height/width of individual cells, but you can change the width of columns/height of rows:  oShape.Table.Columns(2).Width = 123

Comment: Hi Steve. Thats almost works. Here is the correct version: oShape.Table.Columns._Index(2).Width = 123;

Comment: I guess that Columns._Index(2) is a .NET difference from VBA.  Glad to know you've got it sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, thanks to Steve Rindsberg solution would be:

```
oShape.Table.Columns._Index(2).Width = 12;
```

Thats change size of columns in the table pretty well.